# How to use Google api to fetch all reviews of the app in play store if I am not the owner of the app

Tags: google-apis-explorer

Was wondering if its possible to use Google API(Google Play Android Developer API) to list all the reviews of an app even if its not developed/published by me?

How can I get the access token?
Below is the url of API which I found relevant.

GET [https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/reviews](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/reviews)

I  am getting below error after triggering the url with token generated by me by using Try this method option -
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "The caller does not have permission",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}

Please help.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://medium.com/feedis/handle-google-oauth-2-0-api-827e4387e90)?

Comment: Thanks batman. Reason why i asked question is due to this message in the medium link  - "WARNING If you want to use the Google AndroidPublisher API from an app that isn’t associated to your project you will need the app owner to provide you with his client_id and client_secret to continue. "   For eg - if want to list/extract all reviews for Uber, do I need to connect their developers to share client id/secret?

Comment: Yes, I believe you would. I dont think Google allows you to fetch reviews for apps that are not your own so you would need some sort of auth/keys to do so.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick update batman.